# How do i make bootstrap tooltip align properly to the text it is referring to?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tooltip, angular-slickgrid

So the problem i am facing is that ,

When the user is hovering over a column which has *text exceeding the column width* , the tooltip is showing to the mid point of the text when the column will be expanded to see the full text.
I am using a standard bootstrap tooltip with `$().tooltip()`

[image]

In the image you can see that the tooltip is getting shifted to the next column , thats because , when you expand the current column , it will display the full text with its big length and the mid-point for the tooltip then will show properly

So what I need to do is , When the column is shortened ( resized to show less width ) , the tooltip should not show as when the column is fully expanded or fully resized ( currently it is showing the tooltip- triangle  based on the fully expanded(resized) column )

Comment: I doubt that is fixable, but don't know for sure. But, you probably won't get any replies if you don't supply the code to reproduce the problem. Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: The code is really just using data-toggle="tootlip" in the html tag and then using jquery like , $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); , the basic way bootstrap tooltip is implemented.

what i've tried so far is , i tried setting different values for the placement variable inside the tooltip, and also tried it based on different conditions like ,
`if( // text too long ) placement = "left" 
else placement = "bottom"`

Thanks for the reply.